# Modelmapper.map Takes Very Long Time to Convert from DTO to Entity

Tags: spring-boot, performance, optimization, modelmapper

Currently, modelMapper.map to convert from DTO to entity and the other way around takes approximately 3 s.

Is that normal?
Currently, this entity has 12 variables that are using ManyToOne relation.

Previously, it takes 5 s for a single map.

But after I use  modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
now only takes 3 s.

Comment: Please post the code snippets relevant to the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Constructing new ModelMapper instance is generally CPU intensive depending on the complexity of your bindings. You should avoid building new ModelMapper instances for every use and focus on reusing/sharing built instances. If you have different mapping requirements, stash the different shapes in a lookup and compute them lazily when absent.